# Getting syntax highlighting for Go working with Xcode 3 or 4

Tags: xcode

Copied the syntax description files for Xcode included in the Go distribution as described [here](http://golang.org/misc/xcode/go.xclangspec). However it still does not work in either Xcode 3 or 4. Has anyone gotten Go syntax highlighting to work in Xcode?

Comment: You should consider giving more information in your question...

Comment: Well if you install Google Go it contains a misc directory with files describing the syntax of the language so that editors can highlight keywords. There is also one for Xcode I put it in the directory as instructed by the comments in these and it does not work.